# Laravel Policy - Bug or Implementation error?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

I have implemented a user policy in Laravel as follows.

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can list the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        // only a chief editor can view all users
        $authorized = false;
        $authorized = ($user->role->name === 'Chief Editor');
        return $authorized;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\User  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, User $model)
    {
        // only a chief editor or user(who owns the user) can view the user
        $authorized = false;
        $authorized = ($user->role->name === 'Chief Editor' || $user->id === $model->id);
        return $authorized;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        // only a chief editor can create a user
        $authorized = false;
        $authorized = ($user->role->name === 'Chief Editor');
        return $authorized;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\User  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, User $model)
    {
        // only a chief editor or user(who owns the user) can update the user
        $authorized = false;
        $authorized = ($user->role->name === 'Chief Editor' || $user->id === $model->id);
        return $authorized;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\User  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, User $model)
    {
        // only a chief editor or user(who owns the user) can delete the user
        $authorized = false;
        $authorized = ($user->role->name === 'Chief Editor' || $user->id === $model->id);
        return $authorized;
    }
}
```

And here is my user controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreUser;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUser;

use App\User;
use App\Role;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('can:index,App\User')->only('index');
        $this->middleware('can:view,user')->only('show');
        $this->middleware('can:create,App\User')->only('create', 'store');
        $this->middleware('can:update,user')->only('edit', 'update');
        $this->middleware('can:delete,user')->only('destroy');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::paginate(5);
        return view('users.index')
                ->with('users', $users);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        // fetch roles
        $roles = Role::all();
        return view('users.create')
                ->with('roles', $roles);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreUser $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('users.show')
                ->with('user', $user);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('users.edit')
                ->with('user', $user);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdateUser $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

However, when I access an action with multiple parameters in the policy method(two user objects), I get the `This action is unauthorized.` error.

I have also tried returning `true` without any checks from these methods but still the same issue persists.

Is this my code issue or a bug with Laravel?

Comment: instead of authorizing all policies in `__construct` method try authorizing in single methods and check if it works. see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-controller-helpers

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Your code is not working because you'r not passing the second user to the policy.

You'r not using route model binding, so the user passed to the `view` method, for example, does not exist. When the model does not exist, Laravel will not check for the policy and just return false.

The following is an example from the documentation, and it works becuase of the route model binding.

```
Route::put('/post/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->middleware('can:update,post');
```

**The Answer:**

Does not make sense to use authorization in the controller constructor. If you want to use middleware for authorization, attach it to the route not the controller.

If you allow the request to reach the controller, then it would be better to check for authorization in the action not the constructor. It will also be easier to read and debug.

I would remove all the calls to `can` middleware from the constructor and replace it with a call to `authorize` in the action.

You controller should be like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
{
    $this-authorize('index'); // This will check for authorization

    $users = User::paginate(5);
    return view('users.index')
            ->with('users', $users);
}


public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $this->authorize('view', $user);

    return view('users.show')
            ->with('user', $user);
}
```

Also, no need for the temprory variable in your policy class.

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    // only a chief editor can view all users

    return $user->role->name === 'Chief Editor'
}

public function view(User $user, User $model)
{
    // only a chief editor or user(who owns the user) can view the user

    return $user->role->name === 'Chief Editor' || $user->id === $model->id)
}
```

As a side note, in your show action, Why don't you use [implicit route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#implicit-binding)? It would be much cleaner.

```
// web.php

Route::get('users/{user}', 'UserController@show');


// UserController.php

public function show(User $user)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $user);

    return view('users.show', compact('user');
}
```

Comment: Still does not answer why the code is not working even though it is correct.

Comment: I am using `Route::resource('users', 'UserController')` in my routes file which takes care of implicit model binding so I am afraid even the update does not help.

Comment: But you're name the variable `$id` in your `show` method. Try change it `$user`